# TS2339: Property 'contacts' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: node.js, typescript, cordova, npm

I am trying to build a contacts application that uses the Apache Cordova plugins for contacts. When trying to do an `npm run bundle` command for my application it gives me the error in the title above. How do I solve this?

I have tried updating my dependencies in my `package.json` to different versions and I have also tried to get rid of the `"module": "commonjs"` in my `tsconfig.webpack.json` but that didn't work.

```
===========
// index.ts
===========

export class CordovaApp{
    constructor(){
        document.getElementById('findContactButton').addEventListener('click', this.onfindContactButtonClick);
    }

    onfindContactButtonClick(){
        const searchText = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('searchText')).value;
        let fields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName, navigator.contacts.fieldType.name];

        navigator.contacts.find(fields, (contacts) => {
            var ul = document.getElementById('contacts');
            contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.className = 'collection-item';
                li.innerText = contact.displayName;
                ul.appendChild(li);
            });
        }, (error) => {
            alert(error);
        },
        {
            filter: searchText, multiple: true,
            desiredFields: [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName]        
        });

        return false;
    }
}

let instance = new CordovaApp()
```

```
===========
// index.js
===========
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var CordovaApp = (function () {
    function CordovaApp() {
        document.getElementById('findContactButton').addEventListener('click', this.onfindContactButtonClick);
    }
    CordovaApp.prototype.onfindContactButtonClick = function () {
        var searchText = document.getElementById('searchText').value;
        var fields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName, navigator.contacts.fieldType.name];
        navigator.contacts.find(fields, function (contacts) {
            var ul = document.getElementById('contacts');
            contacts.forEach(function (contact) {
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.className = 'collection-item';
                li.innerText = contact.displayName;
                ul.appendChild(li);
            });
        }, function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }, {
            filter: searchText, multiple: true,
            desiredFields: [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName]
        });
        return false;
    };
    return CordovaApp;
}());
exports.CordovaApp = CordovaApp;
var instance = new CordovaApp();
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

```
===========
// package.json
===========
"dependencies": {
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-contacts": "^3.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/cordova": "^0.0.34",
        "@types/cordova-plugin-contacts": "^2.3.0",
        "typescript": "^2.4.1",
        "webpack": "^1.14.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
        "ts-loader": "1.3.3",
        "html-loader": "0.4.4",
        "css-loader": "0.26.1",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.1"
    }
```

```
===========
// Running Command prompt
===========
npm run bundle

[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...

[at-loader] Checking finished with 4 errors
Hash: 52c5912a7e1b4f149e40
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 1014ms
               Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
./www/dist/bundle.js  7.51 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in [at-loader] ./www/js/index.ts:8:33
    TS2339: Property 'contacts' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./www/js/index.ts:8:75
    TS2339: Property 'contacts' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./www/js/index.ts:10:19
    TS2339: Property 'contacts' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./www/js/index.ts:23:39
    TS2339: Property 'contacts' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
```

The code is supposed to bundle correctly an I should have no errors.

Comment: Navigator.contacts is not a standard DOM features. You should try to find some types for whatever adds this object. If it's Apache Cordova, maybe they publish some type files for their extensions. If it doesn't exist, there is a possibility you need to write these types yourself, or cast anything to `any` but that's not as good.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but for whoever's googling it:

Create a `global.d.ts` file in your project's src folder with the following content:

```
declare interface Navigator extends NavigatorExtended {}

interface NavigatorExtended {
    readonly contacts: ContactsManager;
}
// I use only name and tel, but feel free to adjust it https://w3c.github.io/contact-picker/#contacts-manager
type IContact = {
    name: string[],
    tel: string[],
}
interface ContactsManager {
    getProperties(): Promise<string[]>;
    select(properties: string[], options?: any): Promise<IContact[]>;
}
```

it will extend the Navigator typings and make the TS compiler happy :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the following line to src/tsconfig.json within the "files" property:

```
"../plugins/cordova-plugin-contacts/types/index.d.ts"
```

After that you have to restart the running "ionic serve" command (or just rebuild it).

The src/tsconfig.json file should look like this in the end:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts",
    "../plugins/cordova-plugin-contacts/types/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I hope this will help you.
Please note that this is a solution for Ionic 4. Ionic 3 or lower may differ.